# If I click on one check box another check box also checked

Tags: php, html

If I click on one check box another check box also checked.

[image: Error]

### addquiz.php

```
<?php 
$unique_id = time().'_'.uniqid(true); 
$userid = $this->session->userdata('cp_userid');
?> 
<!-- DC QUIZZ -->
<form class="addquizform" id="quiz_form_<?php echo $unique_id;?>" data-form = "<?php echo $unique_id;?>" data-user = '<?php echo $userid ?>'>
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo $sectionId;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="cid" value="<?php echo $courseId;?>">
<div class="dc-quizz-info dc-course-item">
    <div class="dc-content-title">
        <h5 class="xsm black">Quiz : Title of quiz</h5>
        <div class="course-region-tool">
            <input type="button" value = "Save" class="mc-btn-3 btn-style-1 savequiz save" id="save_quiz_<?php echo $unique_id;?>">
        </div>
    </div>      
    <div class="quizz-body dc-item-body">
        <div class="form-item form-checkbox checkbox-style">
            <input type="checkbox" id="showanswer" value="1" name="showanswer">
            <label for="showanswer">
                <i class="icon-checkbox icon md-check-1"></i>
                Show Answer
            </label>
        </div>          
        <div class="form-item form-checkbox checkbox-style">
            <input type="checkbox" id="limittime">
            <label for="limittime">
                <i class="icon-checkbox icon md-check-1"></i>
                Limit time
            </label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="time">
            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="text" name="limittime">
                <label for="">mins</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Quiz Title" class="fullwidth" name="quiztitle">
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Short introduction" class="fullwidth" name="quizintro">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<!-- END / DC QUIZZ -->
```

when I go to add one more quiz it asks to check the check box, but when I clicked on check box above check box also checked. How to over come this problem.

Comment: You Have to post your php code also

Comment: why not use only one checkbox if every time both check-boxes must be checked

Comment: name="showanswer" miss in second check box may be create issue.

Comment: @shashi If I want one more quiz then i need that check box

Comment: @Kevin try http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/GF5wr/2/

Comment: change the name and id of check box and  text box

Answer (score 0):

Please Check The Name as well as id You Defined there is missing an id and name for checkbox

---

```
<div class="dc-quizz-info dc-course-item">
        <div class="dc-content-title">
            <h5 class="xsm black">Quiz : Title of quiz</h5>
            <div class="course-region-tool">
                <input type="button" value = "Save" class="mc-btn-3 btn-style-1 savequiz save" id="save_quiz_<?php echo $unique_id;?>">
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="quizz-body dc-item-body">
            <div class="form-item form-checkbox checkbox-style">
                <input type="checkbox" id="showanswer" value="1" name="showanswer">
                <label for="showanswer">
                    <i class="icon-checkbox icon md-check-1"></i>
                    Show Answer
                </label>
            </div>          
            <div class="form-item form-checkbox checkbox-style">
                <input type="checkbox" name="limitcheck" id="limitcheck">
            </div>

            <div class="time">
                <label for="limittime">
                    <i class="icon-checkbox icon md-check-1"></i>
                    Limit time
                </label>
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" value="" id="limittime" name="limittime">
                    <label for="">mins</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Quiz Title" class="fullwidth" name="quiztitle">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Short introduction" class="fullwidth" name="quizintro">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you send me an file with db .. ??

Comment: i think both id same, how to change the id

Comment: Yaa it's problem of id or name that's why I ask you for the file and db details , so I can check in my local server , what's going wrong

Comment: How can i share?

Comment: Kumarrishikesh12@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156023/discussion-between-kevin-and-rishikesh-kumar).